# Angular: ERROR TypeError: this.panZoomAPI.panDelta is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-changedetection, panzoom

I have made a small ->[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rduaot?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) <- to demonstrate my issue.

I have a master component that has pan-zoom within which there's a parent component that holds some content (the children). The library being used is [ngx-panzoom](https://github.com/TimUnderhay/ngx-panzoom).

Using the default change detection strategy seems to be working fine although in my actual, real-life case I had do to a manual `cdr.detectChanges()` at the very end of my `ngAfterViewInit` function.

In the stackblitz example I have left `ChangeDetectionStrategy` to default and it looks like it's working. The moment I try to trigger a manual change detection (via the private `detectChanges` function) the part where setting the panZoomAPI receives `null`/`undefined` instead of the actual api.

This later on breaks the `resetPanZoom` function which tries to calculate the width of the content and center it so it looks nice.

Any ideas why my `api` is `undefined` if I trigger manual change detection?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the values yourself, `panzoomConfig.api` first emits a value where every entry is `null`.

The second value emited contains all the functions you are looking for. You should likely skip that first value.

```
this.panzoomConfig.api.pipe(takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe), skip(1))
```